# ¿Qué es el error "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2', but no encoding declared"?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x, unicode, ascii

El problema es que me da el siguiente error.

> ```
> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file C:\script.py on line 78, but no encoding declared
> ```

Comenté en el código con detalles. El error a partir de donde puse `#aquí empieza la magia`

```py
#primero decimal binario 1.
def decimal_a_binario(num):
    if num == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return decimal_a_binario(num//2) + str(num % 2) 
    print (decimal_a_binario(num))


#segundo decimal a octal 2.
def decimal_a_octal(n):       
    n1 = n / 8
    resto1 = n % 8
    n2 = n1 / 8
    resto2 = n1 % 8
    n3 = n2 / 8
    resto3 = n2 % 8
    print resto3, resto2, resto1


#tercer decimal a hexagono 3.
def decimal_a_hexagono(H):
    x = (H % 16)
    c = ""
    if (x < 10):
        c = x
    if (x == 10):
        c = "A"
    if (x == 11):
        c = "B"
    if (x == 12):
        c = "C"
    if (x == 13):
        c = "D"
    if (x == 14):
        c = "E"
    if (x == 15):
        c = "F"
    if (H - x != 0):
        return decimal_a_hexagono(H / 16) + str(c)
    else:
        return str(c)
    print decimal_a_hexagono(H)


#cuarto binario a decimal 4.
def binario_a_decimal(x):
    n = len (x)
    valor = 0
    for xs in x:
        if xs == '1':
            valor = valor + 2**(n-1)
        n -=1
    print binario_a_decimal(x) 


#quinto octal a decimal 5.
def octal_to_decimal(number):
    i = 1
    decimal = 0
    while (number != 0):
        reminder = number % 8
        number /= 8
        decimal += reminder * i
        i *= 8
    return decimal

#sexo hexagonal a decimal 6.
def hexadecimal_a_decimal(d):
    print int(d,16)





#aqui empieza la magia
print "¿Hola mae que me diche?"
print "¿Pura vida?"
print "..."
print "..."
print "¿Di mae digame que quiere que haga por ud?" 
#codigo while para poder al menu si la persona lo desea
si = True
while si:
    print "Menu:"
    print "1. Decimal a Binario"
    print "2. Decimal a Octal"
    print "3. Decimal a Hexagono"
    print "4. Binario a Decimal"
    print "5. Octal a Decimal"
    print "6. Hexagono a Decimal"
    opcion = raw_input()
    print opcion
    if opcion == "1":
        print "¿enserio mae?.... tan facil que es "
        num = int(raw_input("Okey mae metame el numero (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): "))
        decimal_a_binario(num)
        si = ("s" == raw_input("Bueno mae ahora quiere que le resuelva algo más o me va a dejar en paz? (lárgate) s/n").lower())

    elif opcion == "2":
        print "¿mae...ud paso la escuela?"
        n = int(raw_input ("Okey mae metame el numero (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): "))
        decimal_a_octal(n)
        si = ("s" == raw_input("Bueno mae ahora quiere que le resuelva algo más o me va a dejar en paz? (lárgate) s/n").lower())

    elif opcion == "3":
        print "mmm ok algo mas decente por lo menos"
        H = int (raw_input("Okey mae metame el numero (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): "))
        decimal_a_hexagono(H)
        si = ("s" == raw_input("Bueno mae ahora quiere que le resuelva algo más o me va a dejar en paz? (lárgate) s/n").lower())

    elif opcion == "4":
        print "mae matese por no saber esto"
        x = int (raw_input("Okey mae metame el numero (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): "))
        binario_a_decimal(x)
        si = ("s" == raw_input("Bueno mae ahora quiere que le resuelva algo más o me va a dejar en paz? (lárgate) s/n").lower())

    elif opcion == "5":
        print "ummmmmmm............"
        number = int (raw_input("Okey mae metame el numero (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): "))
        octal_to_decimal(number)
        print octal_to_decimal(number)
        si = ("s" == raw_input("Bueno mae ahora quiere que le resuelva algo más o me va a dejar en paz? (lárgate) s/n").lower())

    elif opcion == "6":
        print "...... a la puta...como se hacia esta mier?..."
        print "di deme el número mae a ver si lo pego"
        d = int (raw_input("Okey mae metame el numero (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°): "))
        si = ("s" == raw_input("Bueno mae ahora quiere que le resuelva algo más o me va a dejar en paz? (lárgate) s/n").lower())
```

Answer (score 9):

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file C:\script.py on line 78, but no encoding declared`
.

**Problema:** Los scripts de Python usan por defecto la codificación `ASCII` y por eso no "entiende" algunos símbolos, letras (ñ) o las tíldes que están presentes en el español pero no en el inglés.

**Solución:** Debes definir la codificación de caracteres `utf-8` en la primera línea de tu script `.py`.

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 8):

Quiere decir dos cosas: 1. estás utilizando Python 2 (que asume que solo se utiliza ASCII en el código fuente), y 2. por estadística, tienes un acento o quizás una eñe en esa línea. Los anglos no tienen problemas con este tipo de cosas, claro: los caracteres que te van a dar problemas son las vocales acentuadas, diéresis, la eñe...

Si pasas a utilizar Python 3, entonces tus problemas se solucionarán de un plumazo: Python 3 emplea UTF-8 para la codificación de caracteres en archivos. Python 2, como ya hemos comentado, emplea ASCII. Si quieres utilizar una codificación como UTF-8, entonces tienes que indicarlo con un comentario. Este comentario es "casi libre", es decir, Python entenderá varios formatos, como simplemente: `# encoding: utf-8`. Por supuesto, nada de esto sirve de nada si no guardas el *script* (el archivo con extensión `py`), con la codificación UTF-8 en tu editor de textos (hoy por hoy es lo más habitual).

Si quieres utilizar caracteres acentuados dentro de un literal de texto en  Python 2, tendrás el mismo problema. Para indicar que se trata de un literal en UTF-8, tendrás que anteponer una "u" delante de la misma: `u"aquí empieza la magia"`, además del comentario en la parte de arriba del archivo.

Comment: Es bueno añadir siempre la directiva `encoding` informando al intérprete de Python el tipo de codificación usada para guardar el archivo porque, aunque Python 3 considere por defecto que el módulo a interpretar fue guardado con codificación `utf-8`, nadie te asegura que dicho módulo no vaya a ser ejecutado con otra configuración del intérprete distinta a la que tiene por defecto.

Comment: También recuerda que, aparte de informar con `#encoding=utf-8` al intérprete de Python el tipo de codificación usado para guardar el archivo, en el editor de texto utilizado para escribir el código tienes que asegurarte que guardarás ese archivo con ese tipo de codificación concreta. La directiva `encoding` sirve solo para informar al intérprete de Python qué codificación fue usada para guardar el contenido del módulo o archivo, de manera que al leerlo para ser interpretado pueda ser decodificado correctamente. No sirve para guardar el archivo con un tipo de codificación específica.

Comment: He añadido una aclaración sobre lo del editor de textos, aunque hoy por hoy UTF-8 es prácticamente la configuración por defecto.

Comment: Así es, es la configuración por defecto. Pero nada impide que dicha configuración por defecto pueda ser cambiada por alguien de manera personalizada, por lo tanto poniendo siempre la directiva `coding` aseguras que nunca habrá problemas se ejecute donde se ejecute.