# Maximizar una variable con la restricción de una volatilidad fija

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, optimización, maxima

Estoy tratando de crear una optimización de cartera simulada basada en Efficient Frontier sobre 50 acciones, que puede encontrar en [csv aquí](https://airtable.com/invite/l?inviteId=inv1OzctulKIXJvH4&inviteToken=f401f2229125cf0fb7cdf00857e5c3f9041d061d6e8285ec878fca279bb07ffe). Ahora sé cómo conseguir la mejor cartera pero mantiene los pesos libres y estoy buscando una optimización que mantenga esta variable positiva.

Obtengo mi frontera eficiente consiguiendo pesos con una red fija de volátiles σ<sub>p<sub>1</sub></sub>,... σ<sub>p<sub>n</sub></sub>. Entonces para cada σ<sub>p<sub>i</sub></sub>, maximizo los retornos esperados con la restricción de que la volatilidad no sea mayor que σ<sub>p<sub>i</sub></sub>, para obtener μ<sub>p<sub>i</sub></sub>. Entonces σ<sub>p<sub>i</sub></sub>,μ<sub>p<sub>i</sub></sub> son **n** puntos en la frontera eficiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que podemos maximizar los retornos **r** que son iguales a los pesos de los resultados individuales de cada acción **RW**. Esto lleva al siguiente problema de optimización (lo reduje a dos variables para simplificar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que, en forma de matriz, debería ser más o menos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde COV es la matriz de covarianza entre todos los activos.

Sin embargo, sólo pude programarlo sin restricciones de peso **W**.

Aquí, la minimización de un objetivo cuadrático bajo restricciones lineales se puede obtener resolviendo un sistema lineal. Que es realmente fácil de calcular y no tan difícil de entender. Para obtener la mejor relación de agudeza da lo siguiente:

```
def efficient_portfolios(returns, risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e):
    weights_record = []
    volatilities = []
    results = np.zeros((3,len(returns)))
    i = 0
    for portfolio_return in returns:
        A = np.block([[2*sigma, mu, e], [mu.T, 0, 0], [e.T, 0, 0]])
        b = np.zeros(n+2)
        b[n] = portfolio_return
        b[n+1] = 1
        w = np.linalg.solve(A, b)[:n]
        weights_record.append(w)
        portfolio_std_dev = np.sqrt( w.T @ sigma @ w )
        volatilities.append(portfolio_std_dev)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
        i+=1
    return results, weights_record, volatilities

def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e, df):
    results, weights, volatilities = efficient_portfolios(mean_returns,risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e)
    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T

    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T

    print("-"*80)
    print("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print("\n")
    print(max_sharpe_allocation)
    print("-"*80)
    print("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print("\n")
    print(min_vol_allocation)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
    plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)

    return max_sharpe_allocation, min_vol_allocation

stock_prices = pd.read_csv('stocks.csv', index_col=0)
returns = stock_prices.pct_change()
mu = 252 * returns.mean().values
sigma = 252 * returns.cov().values
n = mu.shape[0]

# add risk free asset to mu/sigma
risk_free_rate = 0.0178
z = np.zeros((n,1))
#mu = np.block([mu, risk_free_rate])
#sigma = np.block([[sigma, z], [z.T, 0]])
#n = mu.shape[0]

# solve minimize w'∑w subject to μ'w = r, e'w=1 for varying r
mu = np.expand_dims(mu, axis=1)
e = np.ones((n,1))
returns = np.linspace(risk_free_rate, np.max(mu))


max_sharpe_al, min_vol_al = display_simulated_ef_with_random(returns, risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e, stock_prices)
```

Y da la siguiente trama y portafolios:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation

Annualised Return: 0.63
Annualised Volatility: 0.23


               DD  ADBE  ATVI   APD    NVS      A   ADI    AVB    AYI   AAN  \
allocation -19.33  0.03 -0.32  29.3  12.65 -14.57  2.85 -25.28 -13.17  2.77   

            ...   SWKS    NOV  KMT   MDT   RIO   PSA   STE  POWI  VALE   TX  
allocation  ... -15.61 -10.08 -7.2 -3.16  7.57 -9.39  7.93  5.13  1.07  8.4  

[1 rows x 51 columns]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation

Annualised Return: 0.03
Annualised Volatility: 0.13


             DD  ADBE  ATVI   APD   NVS     A   ADI   AVB   AYI   AAN  ...  \
allocation -0.6 -7.11  5.36  3.81  22.9 -3.69  7.37 -1.27 -1.13 -0.16  ...   

            SWKS   NOV   KMT   MDT   RIO    PSA   STE  POWI  VALE    TX  
allocation  -6.4 -0.25 -9.24  6.15  4.41  19.86 -1.31 -0.23 -2.99  6.05
```

[image]

¿Pero cómo harías si necesitáramos ser siempre positivos? Sé que la solución no puede obtenerse simplemente resolviendo un sistema lineal. Necesitaría usar un [solucionador de optimización cuadrática](https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Consideraciones

Como es algo extensa la respuesta (sólo se admite 30mil caracteres), el código completo está al final de este post, por tanto, sólo durante el desarrollo de esta respuesta, comentaré las funciones y líneas principales con los resultados respectivos para que sea más fácil su lectura.

### Datos iniciales

Dado que se tiene muchos activos (50) tomamos 5 al alzar para comentar que se quiere hacer con ello

```
df = pd.read_csv("stocks.csv", sep=",", engine="python") 
#���Field 1 la columna tiene caracteres extranios
df.columns = ['Field1' if i == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(df.columns)]
df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)


# Seleccionamos 5 activos al azar
activos = np.random.permutation(df.columns)[:5]
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.title('Historico de Algunos Activos', color='gray')
for activo in activos:
    plt.plot(df[activo].to_numpy(), label=activo)
plt.ylabel('Precio del Activo', color='gray')
plt.xlabel('Observaciones', color='gray')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve los activos están a diferentes escalas (precios), hay que re-escalarlos, aunque en el pregunta para ello se emplea `returns = stock_prices.pct_change()` en esta situación en particular es aconsejable usar logaritmos... [¿Por qué usar rendimiento logarítmicos?](https://quantdare.com/por-que-usar-rendimientos-logaritmicos/) con ello se obtiene la siguiente gráfica:

```
df = df / df.shift(1) 
df.dropna(inplace=True)
log_df = np.log(df)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El [Modelo de Frontera Eficiente de Markowitz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Markowitz), requiere una matriz de covarianza (`C`) y unos rendimientos históricos (`p`) que dependiendo de su periodo (diarios semanales, mensual, etc.) estos pueden ser anualizados... en este caso concreto `256 días por año`

```
def metricas_historicas_portafolio(portafolio, dias_anual):
    "... resto del codigo"
    return p, C, numero_de_activos

p, C, numero_de_activos = metricas_historicas_portafolio(log_df, 252)
```

### Rendimiento y Volatilidad

De acuerdo a las colocaciones de nuestro fondo de inversión en un determinado portafolio se obtendrá un rendimiento (mu) y volatilidad (riesgo o sigma) del mismo. Dichas colocaciones corresponderán a unos pesos de relevancia que le hemos dados a cada uno de los activos en nuestro portafolio, estos vienen dados por las siguientes expresiones de matrices:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar `numpy` dichas expresiones se pueden implementar tal cual, pero con una pequeña variación en el orden, por la forma en como fue implementada la función `metricas_historicas_portafolio`... [más detalle en este post en inglés](https://plotly.com/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/markowitz-portfolio-optimization/):

```
def resultados_portafolio(p,w,C):
    mu = w * p.T                           # Rendimiento Esperado
    sigma = np.sqrt(w * C * w.T)           # Volatilidad

    return mu, sigma
```

### Ratio de Sharpe

Es una medida del exceso de rendimiento por unidad de riesgo de una inversión [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_de_Sharpe)

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es útil porque podemos obtener el desempeño de nuestro portafolio, es decir a más grande mejor.

Debido a su importancia hay una función implementada para obtener métricas sobre un conjunto de portafolios

```
def rsharpe_maximo(sharper_ratios, rendimientos, volatilidades):
    "... resto del codigo"
    return maximo_sharpe_ratio, maximo_sharpe_ratio_volatilidad, maximo_sharpe_ratio_rendimiento
```

### Montecarlo

Supongamos que el inversionista quiere colocar `USD $100` este portafolio con `50 activos`... una posible e "ingenua" combinación sería colocar `USD $2 en cada activo`... es decir los pesos sería `[0.02, 0.02, 0.02, ..., 0.2] para cada activo`

Generalmente se simulan los pesos con una [distribución uniforme](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_continua) o [distribución normal estándar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_normal) para obtener pesos "aleatorios" y ver posibles portafolios...

Lo anterior no está mal si son pocos activos... de lo contrario se está obviando [la ley débil de los números grandes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_los_grandes_n%C3%BAmeros) es decir se estaría emulando el comportamiento de un **inversionista [ingenuo](https://www.economicas.unsa.edu.ar/afinan/informacion_general/book/9_SSRN-id986978.pdf)**

Veamos la siguiente función implementada para explicar de que trata

```
def simular_pesos_portafolio(numero_de_activos):
    pesos = np.random.random(numero_de_activos)
    pesos *= sum([np.random.binomial(1, 0.08, numero_de_activos) for _ in range(2)])
    pesos = np.asmatrix(pesos / sum(pesos) )

    return pesos
```

Para evitar lo anterior se añade un generador binomial de `0s` y `1s` con una probabilidad de 0.08 a efecto de que no se invierta en algunos activos... que sucede si todos salen `0s`... como se verá más adelante el `Sharpe Ratio` será `nan`... hay que preocuparse... la respuesta corta y directa es **no**

La idea de simular para este caso concreto, es ver el comportamiento de las posibles opciones que tenemos en la mesa, ya que al existir un modelo matemático robusto para optimizar nuestro portafolio, este debe ser usado por su eficiencia en computo y exactitud.

Simulamos `1000` portafolios con la función `simulacion_de_portafolios` que llama en cada iteración a la función `simular_portafolio` que su vez depende de la función `simular_pesos_portafolio`

```
pesos, rendimientos, volatilidades, sharper_ratios = simulacion_de_portafolios(
    numero_de_portafolios=1000,
    p=p,
    C=C,
    numero_de_activos=numero_de_activos,
    libre_riesgo=0
)
```

También se obtienen las métricas del ratio de sharpe

```
maximo_sharpe_ratio, maximo_sharpe_ratio_volatilidad, maximo_sharpe_ratio_rendimiento = \
rsharpe_maximo(sharper_ratios, rendimientos, volatilidades)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se cambia la semilla `np.random.seed(9062020)` también cambiará las métricas... de lo que se deduce cuál es el **"óptimo"**

### Solvers ("Solucionadores")

Si bien al leer u oír solver se le asocia a Excel, hay que tener presente que es una tecnología que permite minimizar o maximizar una función objetivo para un conjunto de restricciones dadas.

En el enlace proporcionado se da una lista de ["Solvers" no lineales](https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html)... sobre el particular voy a ser honesto, no les he probado todos, por lo general trabajo con *[OR Tools for Python](https://developers.google.com/optimization)* (Herramientas de Investigación de Operaciones para Python) de Google, pero esta tecnología que pertenece a un conjunto de herramientas de Inteligencia Artificial de Google, que es **Open Source**, a la fecha sólo está orientada a modelos lineales.

Para esta respuesta estoy empleando el solver [cvxopt](https://cvxopt.org/examples/index.html#tutorial-examples), porque hay varios ejemplos proporcionados en la red sobre este caso concreto, incluso hay un código ejemplo para la [frontera eficiente](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming), el cuál he tomado pero haciéndole algunas modificaciones, para emplear la función `resultados_portafolio` implementada previamente

```
def portafolio_optimo(p, C, numero_de_activos):
    # Se establece saltos discretos para hallar la
    # la frontera eficiente estos seran los 
    # `targets` u objetivos que se fijan para optimizar
    N = 100
    n = numero_de_activos
    #mus = np.power(10, 5 * np.arange(N) / N - 1) # tiene que ser lista .tolist()
    mus = [ 10**(5.0*t/N-1.0) for t in range(N) ]
    
    # convertir el p y C a matrices del tipo cvxopt
    # en el caso de p se trabaja con su transpuesta
    pbar = opt.matrix(p.T)
    S = opt.matrix(C)

    # Crear las matrices de restricciones
    # Gx <= h
    G = -opt.matrix(np.eye(n))   # matriz identidad negativa n x n 
    h = opt.matrix(0.0, (n ,1))

    # Ax = b
    A = opt.matrix(1.0, (1, n))
    b = opt.matrix(1.0)         # La suma de los pesos es 1


    # Calcular los pesos de la frontera eficiente
    # Empleando Programacion Cuadratica
    # Pero primero silenciamos el solver (es opcional)
    solvers.options['show_progress'] = False
    portafolios = [solvers.qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus]

    # Calcular los rendimientos y volatilidades o riesgos
    # para la frontera eficiente
    # Estas implementaciones funcionan... hay que importar "blas"
    # pero la implementacion que esta fuera de este codigo
    # requiere que se redimensionen los rendimientos, volatilidades
    # para que funcionen
    #rendimientos = [blas.dot(pbar, x) for x in portafolios]
    #volatilidades = [np.sqrt(blas.dot(x, S*x)) for x in portafolios]

    rendimientos, volatilidades = zip(*[
        resultados_portafolio(p, np.array(w).T, C) for w in portafolios
    ])

    # Calcular el portafolio optimo
    #pesos = solvers.qp(opt.matrix(x1 * S), -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] # No funciona para lo que se quiere hacer mas adelante
    pesos = [np.asarray(x) for x in portafolios]

    pesos = np.asarray(pesos)
    rendimientos = np.asarray(rendimientos)
    volatilidades = np.asarray(volatilidades)

    return pesos, rendimientos, volatilidades


w_optimos, mu_optimos, sigma_optimos = portafolio_optimo(p, C, numero_de_activos)
```

La implementación anterior corresponde a un desarrollo formal de

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ellos se genera los puntos para la Frontera Eficiente con los respectivos pesos que dan dichas coordenadas (cada punto es un portafolio)

Pero antes de ellos quiero comentar la siguiente linea

```
mus = [ 10**(5.0*t/N-1.0) for t in range(N) ]
```

Esto contiene los rendimientos objetivos o *targets* los cuales crecen de forma exponencial... lo cuál es válido para un inversionista que busca obtener un desempeño alto de su dinero (similar a las *startups* de TI que crecen x2 x3 x4 anualmente... los llamados unicornios)

Y ¿por qué usar "targets"?... porque al ser la Frontera Eficiente una curva en ella hay infinitos puntos o infinitos portafolios que cae en dicha curva.

En tal sentido, no hay nada esotérico con esos números por defectos, puedes cambiarlos para obtener una curva más fina si así lo deseas (N>100) saltos discretos más pequeños, etc, pero eso sí... que crezca de forma exponencial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Pesos (Colocación)

Cuando se simula hay rendimientos positivos y negativos para un portafolio cualquiera. En el caso de la Frontera Eficiente se aprecia que todos los rendimientos...

Pero esto implica ¿qué los pesos o colocaciones sean necesariamente positivas?

```
w_optimos, mu_optimos, sigma_optimos = portafolio_optimo(p, C, numero_de_activos)

print("\nVerificar cuales suman 1: ")
print(np.array([x.sum() for x in w_optimos]))
# [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
#  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
#  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
#  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
#  1. 1. 1. 1.]

filtrar_pesos_positivos = np.array([(x>=0).all() for x in w_optimos])

print("\nVerificar que todos los pesos sean >= 0: ")
print(filtrar_pesos_positivos)
# [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True False False False False  True False False False False  True
#   True  True False False False False False  True  True  True  True False
#  False False  True  True]
```

El hecho de tener pesos (colocaciones) negativas ya fue ampliamente explicado acá
[Solve(covMat) retorna que system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250022/solvecovmat-retorna-que-system-is-computationally-singular-reciprocal-conditi/250164#250164)

No obstante, se puede descartar dichos portafolios ya que fueron generados `100` quedándonos sólo `84` con esta sentencia:

```
filtrar_pesos_positivos = np.array([(x>=0).all() for x in w_optimos])
```

y actualizando los puntos de la Frontera Eficiente generados previamente

```
w_optimos = w_optimos[filtrar_pesos_positivos]
mu_optimos = mu_optimos [filtrar_pesos_positivos]
sigma_optimos = sigma_optimos[filtrar_pesos_positivos]
```

### Ratio de Sharpe - de nuevo ;) -

Con la función `rsharpe_maximo` y habiéndose descartado aquellos portafolios con pesos negativos, se busca le máximo Ratio de Sharpe para la Frontera Eficiente

```
maximo_rsharpe, maximo_rsharpe_volatilidad, maximo_rsharpe_rendimiento = \
rsharpe_maximo(rsharpe_optimos, mu_optimos, sigma_optimos)
print(maximo_rsharpe)
# 1.27
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Resultado Final (Todo Junto)

Como se sobre-escribió las variables del `portafolio_optimo` se ejecuta (sé que se puede pulir esta parte para reutilizar el código pero la idea en este caso es mostrar un paso a paso para luego optimizar la escritura del código si se requiere)

```
w_optimos, mu_optimos, sigma_optimos = portafolio_optimo(p, C, numero_de_activos)
libre_riesgo = 0
rsharpe_optimos = (mu_optimos - libre_riesgo) / sigma_optimos
rsharpe_optimos = rsharpe_optimos.reshape((1,-1)).reshape((1,-1)) # quitarle dimensiones
```

Como los resultados no van a cambiar (a diferencia de un simulación) y ya se tiene el ratio de sharpe máximo para aquellos portafolios cuyos pesos son positivos, se emplea el siguiente código para capturar su posición en el gráfico final. Aquí el fragmento del código relevante:

```
# Optimo Sharpe Ratio Frontera Eficiente
idx_rshape_optimo = np.where(rsharpe_optimos[0] == maximo_rsharpe)
plt.scatter(
    sigma_optimos.reshape((1, -1))[0][idx_rshape_optimo],   # eje volatilidad
    mu_optimos.reshape((1,-1))[0][idx_rshape_optimo],       # eje rendimientos
    c='#90ff1e', s=100, edgecolors='gray', label=f'Sharpe Ratio Optimo = {maximo_rsharpe:.4f}'
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Notas

- Todos los gráficos (excepto los dos iniciales) está anualizados
  (rendimiento y volatilidad para 252 días al año)
- Se ha empleado `reshape((1,-1))` en las variables `w_optimos, mu_optimos, sigma_optimos` esto por que al trabajar con la función
  `resultados_portafolio` y con algebra lineal se obtienen en
  dimensiones que `matplotlib` no puede leer directamente. Sí en la
  función `portafolio_optimo` quisieras implementar las funciones tal
  cual está en la documentación de cvxopt:

> ```
>   rendimientos = [blas.dot(pbar, x) for x in portafolios]
>
>   volatilidades = [np.sqrt(blas.dot(x, S*x)) for x in portafolios]
> ```

- Vas a tener que tener en cuenta que no se obtendrán las mismas
  dimensiones para `mu_optimos, sigma_optimos` con lo cual tendrás que
  re-implementar toda la parte de abajo (después de la función
  `portafolio_optimo`) para que calcen las dimensiones de los arreglos.
- Debido a que el archivo contiene el siguiente carácter `���Field 1` no sé en que versión lo estás ejecutando quizás esto pueda ayudar [¿Qué es el error “SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2', but no encoding declared”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/qu%C3%A9-es-el-error-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xc2-but-no-encoding-decla)
- o en el terminal ejecutar la siguiente instrucción con el `nombre de tu fichero` sin la extensión `.py` que contiene el código más abajo posteado en mi caso el archivo se llama modeloMarkowitz.py:

> ```
>   $ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python3 -c "import modeloMarkowitz"
> ```

### Código

Como el post es extenso (máximo 30mil carácteres), el código completo que desarrollé, está en mi repositorio de GitHub [ModeloMarkowitz](https://github.com/HubertRonald/ModeloMarkowitz/blob/master/modeloMarkowitz.py)